# In how many ways can $3$ boys and $2$ girls be selected from a group of $6$ boys and $4$ girls?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There is a group of $6$ boys and $4$ girls.

In how many ways can $3$ boys and $2$ girls be selected from a group of $6$ boys and $4$ girls?

**A.** $60$

**B.** $80$

**C.** $120$

**D.** $160$

I tried with $^nC_k$ but I couldn't do it.  This is what I tried: $6!/3!*3!=20$

Comment: When you tried with $_nC_k$, _what_ did you try, exactly? Because that's the way I would do it, you just need to correctly take into account that some kids are boys and some are girls.

Comment: Well, you first choose 3 boys from 6 (${6 \choose 3}$); and then 2 girls from 4 (${4 \choose 2}$). It's not that difficult ...

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{6!}{3!3!} = 20$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3$ boys can be chosen from $6$ boys in $^6C_3$ ways $=\binom{6}{3}$ways

$2$ girls can be chosen from $4$ girls in $^4C_2$ ways $=\binom{4}{2}$ways

Now, the number of combinations $$=\ ^6C_3\cdot^4C_2$$
$$=\binom{6}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}$$
$$=\left(\frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!}\right)$$
$$=120$$
Total number of ways $=120$

Comment: Girls. We need some more females in this choice please.

Comment: Now corrected it.

Comment: 2 girls can be chosen from 4 boys. Sigh.

Comment: Just remove a rib!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially we are asking how many groups of $3$ boys from a pool of $6$ boys are there - answer $^6C_3=\frac{6!}{3!3!}=20$

Similarly, there $^4C_2=\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$ possible groups of girls.  Since these are independent, the total number is $20$ x $6$ $= 120$.

Answer = $120$.